# Finding first occurence of (/) in URL using Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell

I'm new bee in shell scripting, I want to update URL(s) in a file, Example of URL(s) given below from the file.

> http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/restricted universe multiverse deb-src

As per the requirement, only has to update the following part in the URL

> http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/

After updating it should be like

> http://xyz/ubuntu/restricted universe multiverse deb-src

I used **sed** to perform find and replace the URL.

```
sed  "s,http://.*/,http://xyz/," filename.txt
```

But it is replacing the URL till last occurence of **'/'**, as given below

> http://xyz/restricted precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse.

Is there any way to find first occurence of **'/'** in the URL, I googled it, unfortunately did not found any thing. I might miss something.

Any suggestion, appriciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. The `.*` matches everything, as much as it can, the regex is greedy. You want to match *until* `/`. So match `[^/]*` until it.

```
sed 's,http://[^/]*/,http://xyz/,'
```